# Securing HTTP cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I have followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/http) tutorial to create a publicly accessible HTTP cloud function. I want to secure this, ideally with a simple API Key - is this possible?

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access) on securing doesn't seem to cover how to restrict the behaviour, although mentions that you can...

Comment: What do you mean by "secure"? What exactly are you trying to control?

Comment: I'm trying to get data out of 'Zoho' which has really limited functionality / coding options. There is no option to use any of the google cloud libraries, so at the moment we are planning on making POST requests to some 'secure' endpoint and allowing that endpoint to save data into a cloud DB. In terms of 'secure' because of the limitations of the zoho scripting language (Deluge) we will probably have to make do with an API key as a queryparam, or some other option...

Comment: So what exactly is your concern?  Are you worried about passing the API key as a query string parameter to the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to secure this, ideally with a simple API Key - is this possible?

Yes, **securing an HTTP function is possible**, however, [**API keys**](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#api_keys) aren't as secure as the other authentication methods.

Nevertheless, if you prefer to secure your function using the API keys, you'll need to **[deploy a Cloud Endpoints proxy](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions)** and [configure your **securityDefinitions**](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/restricting-api-access-with-api-keys) to enable API key validation.

> The documentation on securing doesn't seem to cover how to restrict the behaviour

By default, any user or service can invoke an HTTP function. However, you can configure Cloud [**Identity and Access Management (IAM)**](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access#controlling_access_on_an_individual_function) on your HTTP function to restrict this behavior. By doing that, you can enable your HTTP function to be invoked only when authentication credentials are provided in the request.

As the mentioned documentation states, you can go to the **Google Cloud Platform Console** and move to **Cloud Functions** from the Console menu. There, you will see the functions that you have in your project:

- In the top right corner, you will see a field “**Show Info Panel**” - please select it. After selecting the appropriate function, you will be able to see there the **Permissions** tab.
- By using the “**Add members**” field, you will be able to enter one or more identities that need access to your function. Once you select a **role** from the drop-down menu, you’ll be able to **add** a new member.

The same article also explains how to **[remove](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access#removing_users)** the existing members from function’s permissions.

**[Here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/iam#access_control_for_users)** you can find more information on access control for users along with available roles.