# Google Cloud Functions http request only by Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a nodejs app deployed on Google App Engine, which trigger http cloud functions, thought simple http call (using axios) to get data from Google Cloud Sql.

Everyone that will use the site will be able to see the http request and to replicate it.

What is the best way to secure my google cloud functions to be called only from google app engine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Securing HTTP cloud function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57608178/securing-http-cloud-function)

Comment: Are you not able to query Cloud SQL directly from GAE?  Do you have to go through Cloud Functions?

Comment: @DenisT. the solution in that post require cloud run and endpoints. Moreover, the features are still in beta and the google app engine has the same service account of the cloud functions, so I don't think is a solution for my problem.

Comment: @DougStevenson yes, it's possible to query Cloud SQL from GAE, but it's not a best practice to build a monolithic application, so I prefer to separate frontend from backend. Moreover I'd like to use my cloud functions in other application.

Comment: On this last comment, I disagree. AppEngine allow you to build a lot of (micro)service and thereby to not have a monolith. Using Cloud Functions instead of a micro-service deployed on AppEngine has no advantage.

Comment: Beta is really stable and efficient on GCP. Simply no SLA, but it works very well

Comment: Beta does not mean stable and does NOT mean that everyone should use it. "At beta, products or features are ready for broader customer testing and use. Betas are often publicly announced. There are no SLAs or technical support obligations in a beta release unless otherwise specified in product terms or the terms of a particular beta program. The average beta phase lasts about six months." https://cloud.google.com/products/#product-launch-stages

Comment: I dont' agree with "AppEngine allow you to build a lot of (micro)service". It's not a good practice to deploy the whole app when you want to modify a single microservice.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to deploy a private function.

- When you deploy your function with the cli use the `--no-allow-unauthenticated` param. This feature is in Beta
- On the console, you can't you when you deploy your function. However, you can delete the access to all user in the functions list page

  - Click on the function line (not the name of the function, the line)
  - Show the info panel in the upper right corner
  - Delete `allUsers` from the cloud function invoker.

[image]

Now authorize only AppEngine to access to your function

- In the console, at the same place (Function Invoker), add the AppEngine default service account : @appspot.gserviceaccount.com
- With the cli, use this command

```
gcloud beta functions add-iam-policy-binding <Your Function Name> \
  --member='serviceAccount:<your project id>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com' \
  --role='roles/cloudfunctions.invoker'
```

Now only the user/service account with the role `cloudfunctions.invoker` could invoke your function.

Comment: Change "Delete allMembers" to "Delete allUsers"

Comment: Already tried this solution, but it's not working for me.
I thought that it was a problem of GCP because cloud functions e GAE have the same service account. 
Do you have prove that this solution actually works to limit the access of Cloud Functions to only App Engine?

Comment: I never try to deploy Cloud Function with the same service account that AppEngine. But, this solution works. If your function is private, only account with the invoker role can call it.

Comment: By default GCP use the same service account between CF and GAE.
I tried again and it's not working.

Comment: This solution doesn't work. Making an http request in an app deployed on google app engine won't get any authorization header to be used with the IAM policy on google cloud functions.

Comment: Wait, do you mean that is your front-end (your Javascript) which call directly your function? Or do you have a backend deployed on AppEngine service, and it's this backend which call the function (In this case, the Javascript know only the backend API)?

Comment: On AppEngine I have my front-end with a reactjs app, calling api from GCF

Comment: Understood. It wasn't clear, I though it was an AppEngine microservice which called the function. But no, it's your javascript, thereby directly the user. Here 2 solutions: Deploy an [ESP](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/esp) or wrap the call in an AppEngine backend service with the security mode described above.

Answer (score 0):

I feel the post mentioned by @Denis T does mention options for your scenario. Since you commented it does not work for your scenario, did you consider restricting access to Cloud Function to only the App Engine default service account? How to do this is mentioned in the answer quoted by Denis.

Comment: Yes, but using IAM on GCF will not work, because I'm calling the cloud functions from my react app on GAE. The http request will not have any authorization header that will match with the IAM profile.

Comment: Just found this https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/service-accounts  that describes using a service account to authorize HTTP requests. It also refers to an example in github. Might be worth checking.